# $\int_M\omega=\int_U\iota^*\omega$ if $\operatorname{supp}(\omega)\subseteq U\subseteq M$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-forms

Let $M$ be an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold and $\omega\in \Omega^n(M)$ with compact support, $U\subseteq M$ open (if necessary you can assume that $U$ is the domain of a chart) and
$$\operatorname{supp}(\omega)\subseteq U.$$
Since $U$ can be viewed as another oriented $n$-dimensional manifold and $\iota^*\omega\in \Omega^n(U)$, we may wonder whether
$$\int_M\omega=\int_U\iota^*\omega$$
To do so, we first need to check that the RHS is well-defined and since I am working with Lee's [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5) this means that I need to check that $\iota ^*\omega$ has compact support. But is this always the case?

---

My failed attempt to show that $\iota^*\omega$ has compact support, in case you are interested:
Since $\operatorname{supp}(\omega)\subseteq U$ it is tempting to conjecture that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\operatorname{supp}(\iota^*\omega)=\operatorname{supp}(\omega)=:A
\end{equation}
and since the subspace topology of $A\subseteq U$ equals the subspace topology of $A\subseteq M$ we would be done. If we introduce the set
$$\{p\in M:\omega(p)\neq 0\}=\{q\in U:(\iota^*\omega)(q)\neq 0\}=:S,$$
then this boils down to showing that the closure of $S$ w.r.t. $U$ equals the closure of $S$ w.r.t. $M$. In particular, to obtain that \begin{equation}\tag{1}
\operatorname{supp}(\iota^*\omega)\subseteq\operatorname{supp}(\omega)
\end{equation}
it suffices to show that $\operatorname{supp}(\omega)\in U$ is a closed subset that contains $S$ and this follows from $U\setminus S=U\cap (M\setminus U)$, but I wasn't able to show the other direction.

Comment: I think that the problem may be solved by showing that the integral of a differential form $\omega\in\Omega^n(M)$ is well defined under the weaker assumption that the the set$$S=\{p\in M:\omega(p)\neq 0\}$$is contained in a compact set $K\subseteq M$. Then we should easily be able to prove that$$\int_M\omega=\int_U\iota^*\omega$$if the aforementioned $K$ can be chosen such that $K\subseteq U$, since $K$ inherits the same topology from $U$ and $M$.